# What is the use of Update element in wix bootstrapper application?

Tags: wix, auto-update

I am trying to implement the auto update feature in wix. I used Update element to do that.

The code that i am using in my application is:

```
<Update Location="D:\Sample\wix\My1stBootStrapper\bin\Debug\"/>
```

If i put the updated setup in the above mentioned location, then the installer is not updating itself. Please tell me how to use the update element in wix.If you provide any samples on that it will be helpful to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Documentation: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/update.html